# In Oracle how do I put certain tables or partitions in a different group so the rest of the db can be brought up with OR without them?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I've done this with MS SQL Server in the past where data that is not required for disaster recovery for instance is in a separate file group and file and not cloned to save significant space and bandwidth.

Example info on the partial restores we used for SQL Server here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190394.aspx

Is something like this possible with Oracle? We're using RAC in case that matters.

To clarify I'm NOT asking about how to setup disaster recovery. Forget about RAC and DR if that adds confusion. How do I put certain tables or partitions in a different group so the rest of the db can be brought up with OR without them.

Comment: Oracle RAC is not disaster recovery solution it's a high availability solution  instead we have got Data Guard.

Comment: Clarified question

Comment: If the objects are in different tablespaces, you can probably do this with a partial RMAN restore, then `drop tablespace xxxx including contents` to drop the TSes you don't need (prolly with the database just in mount mode, otherwise it'll bitch it can't find the datafiles). Just thinking out loud :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put the tables in a different tablespace. Then you can put the datafiles under a different location/group/naming scheme to the rest of the data, and configure your backups to ignore these files.

If you need to recover the database without this data, you should drop the tablespace with the database in mounted mode:

`startup mount;`
`drop tablespace your_unneeded_data including contents;`
`alter database open;`